# React no renderiza las rutas en produccion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-navigation

tengo un problema con una app de React que estoy haciendo, la app esta subida en github pages, lo que me pasa es que no se ve el contenido que renderizan las rutas, y tampoco me da ningun error en consola. En local toda la app se ve correctamente, esto pasa solamente en github pages.

Llegue a la conclusión de que el problema es por las rutas, porque hay un componente "Header" que no esta dentro de una ruta y se renderiza sin problemas.

Este es el link de la app
https://facuaraujo.github.io/logoquiz-esports-game/

Este del repositorio
https://github.com/FacuAraujo/logoquiz-esports-game

```
    render() {        
            if(this.state.levels && this.state.user){
                return(
                    <Router>
                        <Route exact path="/" component={() => {
                            return <Home 
                                        userLevels={this.state.user.levels} 
                                        levels={this.state.levels} 
                                    />
                        }} />

                        <Route exact path="/levels/:levelName" component={(props) => {
                            return <ListTeams 
                                        {...props} 
                                        userLevels={this.state.user.levels} 
                                        levels={this.state.levels} 
                                    />
                        }} />

                        <Route exact path="/levels/:levelName/team/:teamId" component={(props) => {
                            return <Team 
                                        {...props} 
                                        user={this.state.user} 
                                        userId={this.props.user.uid} 
                                        levels={this.state.levels}
                                     />
                        }} />                                       
                    </Router>
                );
            }

            return(
                <div className="loading-page">
                    <svg className="spinner" width="65px" height="65px" viewBox="0 0 66 66" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <circle className="path" fill="none" strokeWidth="6" strokeLinecap="round" cx="33" cy="33" r="30"></circle>
                    </svg>
                </div> 
            );     
        }
```

Comment: Lograste solucionar esto?